# Difference between 2 LSTM Autoencoders

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I would like to know the difference between these 2 Models. the one above has 4 Layers looking into the model summary and you can also define the unit numbers for dimensionality reduction. But what is with the 2nd Model it has 3 layers and you cant directly define the number of hidden units? Are both LSTM Autoencoders for dimensionality reduction and regression analysis ? Are there any good papers describing these two examples that I found from [keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) and[here](http://rickyhan.com/jekyll/update/2017/09/14/autoencoders.html). I did nowhere defined the variables, infact that I am not asking for a coding question directly. I hope this also a good place for this topic. 
1. Model:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, RepeatVector

samples=1000
timesteps=300
features=input_dim=1
data_shape=np.reshape(data,(samples,timestep,input_dim)

inputs = Input(shape=(timestep, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(units, return_sequences=False, name="encoder")(inputs)
decoded = RepeatVector(timestep)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True, name='decoder')(decoded)
autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
print (autoencoder.summary())
```

2. Model:

```
x = np.random.random((1000, 300, 1))
```

2.model:

```
m = Sequential()
m.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(300,1)))
m.add(RepeatVector(300))
m.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
print (m.summary())
m.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mse', 'mape'])
history = m.fit(x, x, nb_epoch=2000, batch_size=100)
```

When I try to add to both of them a data with the shape e.g. (1000, 300, 1) the first one is accepting it the second not, I get the error expected lstm_4 to have shape (None, 300, 100) but got array with shape (1000, 300, 1). With the choosen input_dim 1 and units =100. what am I doing wrong ? This is what I want to be:

```
LSTM(100, input_shape=(300, 1))
```

with units=100
When I run the model, I get the following error: Error when checking target: expected lstm_2 to have shape (None, 300, 100) but got array with shape (1000, 300, 1)

Where is my mistake that the model does not accept my data shape and my units size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two models have no structural difference; they both consist of an encoder followed by a decoder implemented by LSTM layers. The difference is notational; the first model is defined on the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) with the input being considered a layer, whereas the second is defined using the [sequential API](https://keras.io/models/sequential/). As for the encoder-decoder (otherwise known as seq2seq) architecture, it was originally proposed [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1078), and has since evolved greatly, with the most significant improvement being the attention layer.

Answer (score 0):

The number of units for the `LSTM` layers in the second model is the first argument to its initializer, which is 2. That is, if you let `timestep = 10`, `input_dim = 2`, and `units = 2`, then the two models are exactly equivalent.

Comment: When I try to add to both of them a data with the shape e.g. (1000, 300, 1) the first one is accepting it the second not, I get the error expected lstm_4 to have shape (None, 300, 100) but got array with shape (1000, 300, 1). With the choosen input_dim 1 and units =100. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Sounds like you're using `LSTM(1, input_shape=(300, 100))` instead of `LSTM(100, input_shape=(300, 1))`.

Comment: I am correcting it: I used the shape you suggested, but still the same error.

Comment: When I do  LSTM(1, input_shape=(300, 1)), than it is working but thats not what I want, I have one feature and input size of 300 to be reduced to 100 units.

Comment: [The first parameter to `LSTM` is the number of units](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm); could you update your question with the error you got from `LSTM(100, input_shape=(300, 1))`?

Comment: That error should never occur if you used `LSTM(100, input_shape=(300, 1))`; please provide your full model including the relevant data. If you use that layer and let e.g. `x = np.random.random((1000, 300, 1))`, then you'll find that e.g. `m.predict(x)` works as expected, `m.predict(x).shape` being `(1000, n, m)`, where `n` is the number of repetitions used in `RepeatLayer`, and `m` being the number of units used in the second instance of `LSTM`. As long as your input shape is `(None, 300, 1)`, the model will compile regardless of the choice of units in the first `LSTM`.

Comment: full modell with random data as you suggested, but still not compiling

Comment: The compilation runs fine here. The fitting, however, does not. You can't use your input data as the target data, i.e. the second parameter in `m.fit`, since the shape of the output of the model differs from the input (as evident from the final line in the "Output shape" column in your model summary).

Comment: I checked the model summary, you are right. what would you say to do than, what am I have to improve?

Comment: If you want to achieve the same effect as in the first model, rather than `m.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))`, use `m.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True))`

Comment: For the second `LSTM` layer, yes.

Comment: thank you, I will try both out and bring my solutions later online for sharing